# Pivoting unique users for each month, each year

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm learning about PIVOT function and I want to try it in my DB, in the table `DDOT` I have events (rows) made by users during X month Y year in the YYYYMM format.

```
id_ev iddate id_user ...
------------------------
1     201901 321
2     201902 654
3     201903 987
4     201901 321
5     201903 987
```

I'm basing my query on the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) and I'm not getting errors but I'm not able to fill it with the SUM of those unique events (users). In simple words I want to know how many users (unique) checked up each month (x axis) in the year (y axis). However, I'm getting NULL as result

```
YYYY    jan     feb     mar
----------------------------
2019    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I'm expecting a full table with what I mentionted before.

```
YYYY    jan     feb     mar
----------------------------
2019    2       1       1
```

In the code I've tried with different aggregate functions but this block is the closest to a result from SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE ddot
(
 id_ev   int NOT NULL ,
 iddate  int NOT NULL ,
 id_user int NOT NULL 

);

INSERT INTO DDOT
(
 [id_ev], [iddate], [id_user]
)
VALUES
(
 1, 201901, 321
),
(
 2, 201902, 654
),
(
 3, 201903, 987
),
(
 4, 201901, 321
),
(
 5, 201903, 987
)
GO

SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_user) [TOT],
                DATENAME(YEAR, CAST(iddate+'01' AS DATETIME)) [YYYY], --concat iddate 01 to get full date
                DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(iddate+'01' AS DATETIME)) [MMM]

        FROM DDOT
        GROUP BY DATENAME(YEAR, CAST(iddate+'01' AS DATETIME)),
                DATENAME(MONTH, CAST(iddate+'01' AS DATETIME))
) AS DOT_COUNT
PIVOT(
        SUM([TOT])
        FOR MMM IN (jan, feb, mar)
) AS PVT
```

Comment: `201902` isn't a date(time), and as a datetime it's `2452-10-15`. None of those `dates" fall in January, February, or March, and hence why it's not working as you expect. Use proper dates, and you'll get proper results. :)

Comment: The crux of your issue is storing dates as ints. Try running just the inner query. You get only a single row for October. Use the date datatype instead and this will be a LOT easier. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Correction, the value you're converting to a date is a value like `201904` (`201903 + '01' = 201903+1 = 201904`), which is actually `2452-10-17 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: If you correct your data type, you still don't actually get the results you are after due to the `DISTINCT`, and if you take that away, you don't get the right results either. So something isn't right here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=00cbaef653b3d402b87d8b6abfa39046)

Comment: @Larnu You are right, I switched it to nvarchar and adding `'01'` converts the date properly to my computer's dateformat but I'm still getting null results.

Comment: @SeanLange , before switching iddate to nvarchar and back to datetime the inner query works correctly and matches main data. It's the pivot not working.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should be using an actual date in the `iddate` column, and not a string (number?).  We can workaround this using the string functions:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(4), LEFT(iddate, 4)) AS YYYY,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(2), RIGHT(iddate, 2)) = '01' THEN 1 END) AS jan,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(2), RIGHT(iddate, 2)) = '02' THEN 1 END) AS feb,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(2), RIGHT(iddate, 2)) = '03' THEN 1 END) AS mar,
    ...
FROM DDOT
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(varchar(4), LEFT(iddate, 4));
```

Note that if the `iddate` column already be text, then we can remove all the ugly calls to `CONVERT` above:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(iddate, 4) AS YYYY,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(iddate, 2) = '01' THEN 1 END) AS jan,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(iddate, 2) = '02' THEN 1 END) AS feb,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(iddate, 2) = '03' THEN 1 END) AS mar,
    ...
FROM DDOT
GROUP BY
    LEFT(iddate, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I already switched it to NVARCHAR. I know I can do the pivot manually but my DW contains 10 years of data and doing each line for each month. O O F.

Comment: Well consider sticking with the traditional pivot, as often it can outperform SQL Server's `PIVOT` query.